# Pasar un String a un TextView

Tags: android-studio, textview

estoy realizando una app en Android Studio por medio de la cual leo remotamente un archivo txt, seguidamente paso los datos leidos a una matriz de strings y después asigno un elemento de esa matriz a un TextView para mostrarlo por pantalla, aunque el proceso se realiza correctamente la app no me muestra el dato que asigno al TextView.

aquí os dejo el código para ver dónde tengo el problema.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String VersioRemota;
String Temp;
TextView Tv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            URL url = null;

            try {
                url = new URL("http://www.inforatge.com/alzira/main/wdl/clientraw.txt");

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[730];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                bytesRead = bis.read(buffer);
                VersioRemota = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                String Datos[] = VersioRemota.split(" ");
                Temp = Datos[4];

                bis.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.w("", "MALFORMED URL EXCEPTION");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
            }

        }

    }).start();
    Tv1=(TextView) findViewById ( R.id.TextView1 );
    Tv1.setText(Temp);

}


}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="116dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="116dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="temperatura"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

Comment: Usa AsyncTask que tiene ya metodos listos para eso

Comment: ¿Acaso `Temp` está realmente tomando algún dato. Cambia esto `Tv1.setText(Temp);` por esto temporalmente: `Tv1.setText("Lorem ipsum");` y di si no muestra nada. Confirma que estás cargando el layout correcto.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta de @IgmerRodriguez por eso es importante revisar el LogCat, de lo contrario tardaras horas o dias tratando de resolver un problema que el mismo LogCat te podría ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estas crean un tarea que se esta ejecutando en un hilo diferente del principal digamos que en segundo plano,para mostrar el resultado debes implementar `runOnUiThread`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String VersioRemota;
String Temp;
TextView Tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrueba);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            URL url = null;

            try {
                url = new URL("https://www.inforatge.com/alzira/main/wdl/clientraw.txt");

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                byte[] buffer = new byte[730];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                bytesRead = bis.read(buffer);
                VersioRemota = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                String Datos[] = VersioRemota.split(" ");
                Temp = Datos[4];
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Tv1.setText(Temp);
                    }
                });

                bis.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.w("error**", "MALFORMED URL EXCEPTION");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w(e.getMessage(), e);
            }

        }

    }).start();
    //
    //Tv1.setText(Temp);
}
}
```

Comment: Con tu respuesta todo OK. Sabes si se le puede pasar directamente a un TextView el valor de una posición de la matriz de strings Datos, así evitaria usar la variable Temp.